# Component cannot be used as an entry component

Tags: webpack, angular5, ng-modules

```
import { SpinnerComponent, ExternalLibrary } from 'external.library'
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, ExternalLibrary
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
  , entryComponents: [SpinnerComponent]
})
```

Above is my code to specify entryComponent to a module.
also this SpinnerComponent is from an external module which is ExternalModule.

Webpack giving error:

> ERROR in SpinnerComponent cannot be used as an entry component.

Is belonging to the same module a requirement for a component to appear in entryComponents property list?

As far as I can go through the official definitions there is no such pre requisite specified for a component before appearing in entryComponent property.

Comment: Can you post the implementation of `SpinnerComponent`? There are requirements for an entry component that the component is not meeting.

Comment: @dook Do you have any details on those requirements? I'm struggling with the same for module components created with `ViewContainerRef.createComponent`.
Some as simple as this https://gist.github.com/lars-erik/df41d1d889264b3ff2c1de1826ca936d

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I have the exact same issue.

Comment: I didn't also not working on Angular these days... will update once I have any answer.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue. What fixed it for me was adding the component to the `entryComponents` of a module in my external library.

In your case that would mean updating the `ExternalLibrary` NgModule to include `SpinnerComponent` as an entry component instead of the app that's using the library.

```
@NgModule({
    ...
    entryComponents: [SpinnerComponent]
    ...
})
export class ExternalLibrary { }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error still persisted even after adding it to `entryComponents` inside the library module. Turned out it was because of my `index.ts` file: Inside the folder of the module I had an `index.ts` file which was re-exporting the module and its components. Inside `public_api.ts` I used the export from the `index.ts`, so it looked something like this:

```
...
export * from './lib/shell';
```

Somehow Angular does not like `index.ts` files inside libraries, and I got the error (language service was also throwing errors, not recognizing the tags). Changing `index.ts` to `public-api.ts` fixed it:

```
...
export * from './lib/shell/public-api';
```

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the dynamic component from declarations

```
import { SpinnerComponent, ExternalLibrary } from 'external.library'
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent, SpinnerComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, ExternalLibrary
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
  , entryComponents: [SpinnerComponent]
})
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was that the entry component was declared in an Angular Library, but, it was redeclared in diferent lacy load modules (as entry component again), cleaning the declaration in the lacy loads module and keeping only the declaration inside the library, works.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

###### Hello @Ashutosh,

Try removing this line:

<strike>entryComponents: [SpinnerComponent]</strike>

Reshuffle items by adding SpinnerComponent to declarations, like so:

```
import { SpinnerComponent, ExternalLibrary } from 'external.library'
  @NgModule({
   declarations: [AppComponent, SpinnerComponent],
   imports: [BrowserModule, ExternalLibrary],
   bootstrap: [AppComponent]
  })
```